# How to select records with two columns matching values in one table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a table with the below structure and data:

```
create table employee (id int, name varchar, father_name varchar);
insert into employee values(1, 'John', 'Alex'),(2, 'Simi', 'Expatri'),(3, 
'John', 'Alex'),(4, 'Hezad', 'Ambrose'),(5, 'John', 'Alex'), (6, 'Simi', 
'Expatri'), (7, 'Hezad', 'Ambrose'), (8, 'John', 'Reman'), (9, 'Komal', 
'Ambrose');
```

Now I want to fetch those records whose two columns `name` and `father_name` match each other.
The desired result would be as following:

```
id    |    name    |    father_name
1     |    John    |    Alex  
3     |    John    |    Alex  
5     |    John    |    Alex  
2     |    Simi    |    Expatri  
6     |    Simi    |    Expatri  
4     |    Hezad   |    Ambrose  
7     |    Hezad   |    Ambrose
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: `order by father_name, name`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Yes, they should come together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering by `name` and `father_name` is the first step, but I assume you don't want records where no other matching records are found. This would work:

```
select e1.id, e1.name, e1.father_name
  from employee as e1
  inner join employee as e2
    on e1.name = e2.name
   and e1.father_name = e2.father_name
   and e1.id != e2.id
  group by e1.id, e1.name, e1.father_name
  order by e1.name, e1.father_name
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dc51e/1) is a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, name, father_name
  from employee
  where (name, father_name) in (
     select name, father_name
       from employee
       group by name, father_name
       having count(*) > 1
     )
  order by father_name, name
```

Comment: Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (Help Centre)_ In the section **Answer the question** there is a short sentence which reads: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._ You might want to consider [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217761/15356) your answer and adding an explanation of why your answer is better. Your answer might be flagged as **very low quality**.